# Exception rethrown at [0]:

Tags: .net, exception, stack-trace

I'm investigating a stack trace, and I came accross this output:

```
Server stack trace: 
   ...
   at MyProject.Data.Notifications.NotificationCache.InitialisedCache() in NotificationCache.cs: line 72
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at MyProject.Data.Notifications.NotificationCache.AddItemToCache(NotificationDto dto) in NotificationCache.cs: line 82
bla bla bla
```

Could somebody please explain what the `Exception rethrown at [0]:` means and show some simple scenario how to replicate it?
I tried to replicate it via try/catch/throw, try/catch ex/throw ex etc but I could not.

Comment: Can you post the lines around line 82 and line 72 from NotificationCache.cs?

Comment: That is just an example, it is not important. I would like to undestand when I get Exception rethrown at [0]: what is going on and why it is there? I suspect it might have something to with async calling but I might be wrong. In this particular case, I found the source code of the private method Lazy<T>.CreateValue http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/249448-System.Lazy%601%5BT%5D.CreateValue%28%29# but I'm not sure why it prints Exception rethrown at [0]: and my simple console application example with rethrowing is not doing it.

Comment: Yes, but line 82 is where the re-throw is happening. Can you please post just around line 82 in your question and identify it so we don't need to download the code and count the lines. (also we don't know if you added or removed any so the count could be off)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Lazy<T>.CreateValue` calls `Exception.PrepForRemoting()`, which is where the "Exception rethrown at [0]" bit gets added.  This is a bit of an odd design choice on the author's part, but presumably he was using it as a way to get the "split" stack trace that would allow you to see both the code that caused the exception and the code that called it, despite the fact that the former is invoked via a delegate.

Comment: great! I found the code which is simply adding a string into the stack trace: http://typedescriptor.net/name/members/1168BF1E465B5ACA5B5B4CFAB2CE29CC-System.Exception.PrepForRemoting%28%29

Comment: fixed the link to the [Exception.PrepForRemoting() source code](http://dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFXspW7/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Exception@cs/1/Exception@cs)